# How to remove users from chat in odoo8?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I just wanna ask you that How to remove users from instant messaging in odoo. These are the users are who don't belongs to any of groups in my module.Please help me out.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

**Follow Step :**

1) Goto Setting >> Users >> Users.

2) Select Your user Which is not display in odoo Chatter.

3) Edit and "Active" Filed Unchecked.

4) Refresh it and see The user is remove in Chatter.

**See In Image :** [image]

Comment: I have to do it automatic as if user doesn't belongs to any group in res.users.

Answer (score 0):

You can set chat rules via security section in your im_chat addon folder. (/openerp/addons/im_chat/security).